# Make hint for Android spinner using enums

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I can't find a solution to my problem : I want a hint text displayed on my Spinner but the adapter I set only accepts enum type (IdentityType enum)so I cannot add a String to it (for the hint)

Do you have any solution still using the enum in the adapter?

```
private fun initDriverIdentityTypeSpinner() {
    driverIdentityTypeSpinner.adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<IdentityType>(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,IdentityType.values()) {
        override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View =
            (super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent) as CheckedTextView).also{
                it.setText(getItem(position)!!.stringRes())
            }
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) =
            (super.getView(position, convertView, parent) as TextView).also {
                it.setText(getItem(position)!!.stringRes())
            }

        override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean = position != 0

    }.also {
        it.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    }
}

//IdentityType Extension
@StringRes
fun IdentityType.stringRes(): Int {
    return when(this) {
        IdentityType.DRIVING_LICENSE -> R.string.driving_license
        IdentityType.ID_CARD -> R.string.id_card
        IdentityType.PASSPORT -> R.string.passport
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `IdentityType` your class? Can you edit it?

Comment: IdentityType is my enum and contains DRIVING_LICENSE, ID_CARD and PASSPORT values and I can't edit it, it's contained in the domain layer

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin there is possibility to put properties inside enum (here it calls enum class). You can define it in constructor like following:

```
enum class IdentityType(val stringResId: Int) {
    DRIVING_LICENSE(R.string.driving_license),
    ID_CARD(R.string.id_card),
    PASSPORT(R.string.passport)
}
```

Then you can use it like it is a common property of a class.

```
val type: IdentityType = ...
val string = getString(type.stringResId)
```